# D3 - using strings as axis ticks

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hi have the following domain `array=["Col 1", "2012", "total"]` and I create the scale this way

```
x = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(array)
        .rangeRoundBands([0,width], .1);
```

And I call the axis this way:

```
 d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x);
```

Unfortunately this creates unstable behaviour and the data swap on redraw as demonstrated here: http://jsbin.com/ibewux/9/edit

The only way to have a stable behaviour is to have numeric values for the domain, namely array=[0, 1, 2, 3, ...]

How can I display ticks of this format ["Col 1", "2012", "total",..., "any string"] instead of numeric ones (i.e., [0,1,2,...N]) and avoid that the data charted swap (apparently on different random ticks each time) on redraw?

Many thanks

Comment: What do you mean by “ticks swap on redraw”? It would help if you could link to an example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ibewux/9/edit

Answer (score 3):

It’s already the case for [ordinal scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales) that the [axis](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes) ticks are the [domain values](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#wiki-ordinal_domain). As shown here:

- http://bl.ocks.org/3259783

Setting [axis.tickValues](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickValues) to the scale’s domain here is redundant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The jsbin was in the link in my question: http://jsbin.com/ibewux/9/edit. Following your advice the ticks do not swap but now the data do swap. Can't get my head around this. Thanks.

Comment: If I use numeric values for the domain everything works. Moving to strings the data are drawn on a different (and apparently random) tick.

Comment: You need to [use a key function with your data-join to maintain object constancy](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/).

Comment: I have tried but cannot manage to stop the swapping behaviour. I will probably format ticks blank and add custom text as a workaround. I would appreciate if you could create a simple example in the API where you demonstrate how to deal with this row (series) / column (points) data structure (.series / Object). The constancy example and API are on a simpler data structure and I am failing to adapt it to this one. Many thanks.